# Inserting an item into a backbone.js collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a straightforward way to insert a new model item into the middle of a backbone.js `Collection` and then update the collection's `View` to include the new item in the correct position?

I'm working on a control to add/delete items from a list. Each list item has its own `Model` and `View`, and I have a `View` for the entire collection as well.

Each item view has a `Duplicate` button that clones the item's model and inserts it into the collection at the index position below the item that was clicked.

Inserting the item into the collection was straightforward, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to update the collection view. I've been trying something like this:

```
ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#list-rows',
    initialize: function () {
      _.bindAll(this);
      this.collection = new Items();
      this.collection.bind('add', this.addItem);
      this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
      this.collection.each(this.addItems);
      return this;
    },
    addItem: function (item) {
      var itemView = new ItemView({ model: item }),
          rendered = itemView.render().el,
          index = this.collection.indexOf(item),
          rows = $('.item-row');

      if (rows.length > 1) {
        $(rows[index - 1]).after(rendered);
      } else {
        this.$el.append(rendered);
      }
    }
}
```

This implementation is sort of working, but I'm getting strange bugs when I add a new item. I'm sure I can sort those out, but ...

There's a voice in my head keeps telling me that there's a better way to do this. Having to manually figure out where to insert a new `ItemView` seems really hacky--shouldn't the collection view know how to rerender the collection already?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way I'm doing is let the `ListView` render each `ItemView` in its `render` function. Then I just bind the `add` event to the `render` function, like this:

```
ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#list-rows'
  , initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.collection = new Items();
    this.collection.bind('add', this.render);
    this.render();
  }
  , render: function () {
    this.$el.empty();
    var self = this;
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
      self.$el.append(new ItemView({ model: item }).render().el);
    });
    return this;
  }
}
```

Everytime you call `this.collection.add(someModel, {at: index})`, the view will be re-rendered accordingly.

Comment: I had to add a call to `(.item-row).remove()` inside the `render` method to get this to work, but it's a good solution. (Otherwise the rerendered items were getting added to the end of the existing rendered items.) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, you can just do `this.$el.empty()` to clear the `$el` before looping through the collection :)

Comment: That's exactly how I'm adding items to the collection currently. It's putting the new item in the correct spot in the collection. I noticed that I have a couple of typos in my comment above: I'm calling `$('.item-row').remove()` to clear out the items that were created the last time the collection was rendered. It's just resetting the view. Come to think of it, there is a `reset` method that might do what I want. I'll try calling that and then calling `render`.

Comment: this is not ideal as it re-renders the entire collection view when only a single model is added

Comment: I guess it all depends on how we want to tackle the problem. You can go all crazy with JavaScript/jQuery trying to find the exact location to insert and remove the view for a certain model. Or if number of models are small, clearing out the whole thing and re-render it does not seem too bad.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think re-rendering the whole collection when adding a new element is the best solution.  It's slower than inserting the new item at the right place, especially if the list is long.

Also, consider the following scenario.  You load a few items in your collections, and then you add `n` more items (say the user clicks a "load more" button).  To do this you would call the `fetch()` method passing `add: true` as one of the options.  As the data is received back from the server, the 'add' event is fired `n` times and you'd end up re-rendering your list `n` times.

I'm actually using a variant of the code in your question, here's my callback to the 'add' event:

```
var view, prev, prev_index;
view = new ItemView({ model: new_item }).render().el;
prev_index = self.model.indexOf(new_item) - 1;
prev = self.$el.find('li:eq(' + prev_index + ')');
if (prev.length > 0) {
    prev.after(view);
} else {
    self.$el.prepend(view);
}
```

So, essentially I'm just using the `:eq()` jQuery selector instead of getting all the elements as you do, should use less memory.

Comment: This works great, but I'm displaying numbers next to each item in the list, so I need to re-render to keep the numbers in sync.  Can't see any way around that. Bummer....I like the simplicity here.